# WP Desk Dropshipping plugin settings for variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import-from-excel

I downloaded the pro version of WP Desk dropshipping plugin and I am trying to import some products from an online xml file that I got from the merchant.
The plugin gives me a few options for variations but it doesn't work the way I want it. The only common variable that same product variations have is the model number.
I have attached screenshots of xml variation product and the settings wp desk plugin gives me in case anyone can help.
Thanks
[[xml of product variation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmriD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMy3q.png)
[wp desk settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HGgi.png)

I have tried all the combinations at least I think so..but variation products don't show in the right way. Only simple products.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.